# nokia cell phone not accepting IP from dnsmasq dhcp server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, nokia

I having problem connecting a NOkia cell phone to my home wifi network.

The wifi network is provided by a wireless card in a machine
running Debian Testing and 2.6.26-2-686 kernel. The cars is D-Link
DWL-G520 working in ap mode and has WPA encryption enabled.

The wireless network is provided by hostapd using madwifi driver.
Windows and Mac machines work properly with this wifi network.

When I try to get the Nokia phone to connect to the wifi network, I get
these lines in my dnsmasq log (to see lines without wrapping, here is
the pastebin link for convenience - http://pastebin.com/m466c8fd2):

```
Oct 27 13:25:21 red hostapd: ath0: STA 11:22:33:44:55:66 IEEE 802.11:
disassociated
Oct 27 13:25:21 red hostapd: ath0: STA 11:22:33:44:55:66 IEEE 802.11:
associated
Oct 27 13:25:21 red hostapd: ath0: STA 11:22:33:44:55:66 RADIUS:
starting accounting session 4AE664FA-00000036
Oct 27 13:25:21 red hostapd: ath0: STA 11:22:33:44:55:66 WPA: pairwise
key handshake completed (WPA)
Oct 27 13:25:21 red hostapd: ath0: STA 11:22:33:44:55:66 WPA: group key
handshake completed (WPA)
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 Available DHCP
range: 192.168.5.150 -- 192.168.5.199
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 DHCPDISCOVER(ath0)
0.0.0.0 11:22:33:44:55:66
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 DHCPOFFER(ath0)
192.168.5.21 11:22:33:44:55:66
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 requested options:
12:hostname, 6:dns-server, 15:domain-name,
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 requested options:
1:netmask, 3:router, 28:broadcast, 120:sip-server
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 tags: known, ath0
```

Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 next server:
192.168.5.1
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  1
option: 53:message-type  02
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option: 54:server-identifier  192.168.5.1
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option: 51:lease-time  00:00:46:50
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option: 58:T1  00:00:23:28
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option: 59:T2  00:00:3d:86
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option:  1:netmask  255.255.255.0
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option: 28:broadcast  192.168.5.255
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option:  3:router  192.168.5.1
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  4
option:  6:dns-server  192.168.5.1
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  8
option: 15:domain-name  home.pvt
Oct 27 13:25:21 red dnsmasq-dhcp[11451]: 3875439214 sent size:  3
option: 12:hostname  NokiaCellPhone

Anybody know the problem might be?

If I switch off dnsmasq dhcp queries logging, i.e. if I decrease the verbosity
of the log, all I see are two lines of DHCPDISCOVER(ath0) and
DHCPOFFER(ath0) repeatedly in the log with no acceptance by the cell
phone.

It appears as though the phone is not accepting the dhcp offer.

However, if I give the phone a static IP address in its configuration,
it works properly on the wifi network. So it appears as though the
problem is dhcp related.

Hints? Suggestions?

Installed stuff:

```
$> dpkg -l dnsmasq hostap* | grep ^i
ii  dnsmasq       2.50-1  A small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
ii  dnsmasq-base  2.50-1  A small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
ii  hostapd       1:0.6.9-3  user space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/
```

Thanks.
PS: Here is the DHCP tcp dump for more information (with mac addresses changed):

---

```
$> sudo dhcpdump -i ath0 -h ^11:22:33:44:55:66
  TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:32.916

    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)

 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)

  HLEN: 6

  HOPS: 0

   XID: c3f93d53

  SECS: 0

 FLAGS: 7f80

CIADDR: 0.0.0.0

YIADDR: 0.0.0.0

SIADDR: 0.0.0.0

GIADDR: 0.0.0.0

CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00

 SNAME: .

 FNAME: .

OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)

OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0

OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66

OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)

                                              6 (DNS server)

                                             15 (Domainname)

                                              1 (Subnet mask)

                                              3 (Routers)

                                             28 (Broadcast address)

                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)
```

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:32.918
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:32.918
    IP: 192.168.5.1 (a:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.5.21
SIADDR: 192.168.5.1
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.5.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      18000 (5h)
OPTION:  58 (  4) T1                        9000 (2h30m)
OPTION:  59 (  4) T2                        15750 (4h22m30s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.5.255
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.5.1
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.5.1
OPTION:  15 (  8) Domainname                home.pvt

### OPTION:  12 (  3) Host name                 Nokia_E63

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:34.922
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 2
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:34.922
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 2
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:34.923
    IP: 192.168.5.1 (a:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 2
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.5.21
SIADDR: 192.168.5.1
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.5.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      18000 (5h)
OPTION:  58 (  4) T1                        9000 (2h30m)
OPTION:  59 (  4) T2                        15750 (4h22m30s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.5.255
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.5.1
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.5.1
OPTION:  15 (  8) Domainname                home.pvt

### OPTION:  12 (  3) Host name                 Nokia_E63

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:38.919
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 6
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:38.920
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 6
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:38.921
    IP: 192.168.5.1 (a:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: c3f93d53
  SECS: 6
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.5.21
SIADDR: 192.168.5.1
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.5.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      18000 (5h)
OPTION:  58 (  4) T1                        9000 (2h30m)
OPTION:  59 (  4) T2                        15750 (4h22m30s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.5.255
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.5.1
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.5.1
OPTION:  15 (  8) Domainname                home.pvt

### OPTION:  12 (  3) Host name                 Nokia_E63

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:46.944
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: ccafe769
  SECS: 14
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:46.944
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: ccafe769
  SECS: 14
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        0.0.0.0
OPTION:  61 (  7) Client-identifier         01:11:22:33:44:55:66
OPTION:  55 (  7) Parameter Request List     12 (Host name)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                              1 (Subnet mask)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            120 (SIP Servers DHCP Option)

### OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:46.945
    IP: 192.168.5.1 (a:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: ccafe769
  SECS: 14
 FLAGS: 7f80
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.5.21
SIADDR: 192.168.5.1
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 11:22:33:44:55:66:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.5.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      18000 (5h)
OPTION:  58 (  4) T1                        9000 (2h30m)
OPTION:  59 (  4) T2                        15750 (4h22m30s)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.5.255
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.5.1
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.5.1
OPTION:  15 (  8) Domainname                home.pvt

### OPTION:  12 (  3) Host name                 Nokia_E63

TIME: 2009-10-30 12:15:48.952
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (1:22:33:44:55:66) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
... and so on ...

Comment: What would probably be more handy would be a full (whole packet) tcpdump of the DHCP traffic between the phone and the server.  Double bonus points if you've also got a capture between the phone and a DHCP server/session that does work.  My bet's on the phone's DHCP client implementation just being crap.

Comment: I will try to get that data as well.

I am also having a similar problem with an iphone though, but I do not have that device handy at the moment.

Comment: Added the dhcpdump info (but screwed up the formatting somehow :-(  ).

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is requesting option 120 (sip-server), amongst others.  The other values are being returned, but that one isn't.

As far as I know such requests are optional, but it's possible that the Nokia can't cope with not getting a value for that option.

Comment: Yep. I've had this problem before.  Can't for the life of me remember what we did to make it work! Sorry!